# backup electrical feed to main panel from inverter's GFCI outlet without ground?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, inverter

I have rigged a 1000watt/120vac inverter to my EV, to use for backup electrical power during short grid outages (the main "traction" battery has 40kwh and the DC-to-DC converter is known to be able to supply 135 amps to the 12v system). The inverter has duplex GFCI outlets.

I could just run extension cords to the few loads I'd like to support (fridge, modem, a few lights), but I'd prefer to feed the main panel (using an interlock, of course).  I'll probably just feed one phase of the panel, and shuffle a couple of breakers if necessary to get the loads I want (though feeding both phases from the 120vac may be possible, see: [feeding both sides of load center from 120vac backup source](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172982/feeding-both-sides-of-load-center-from-120vac-backup-source)).

The problem is, ground and neutral are (of course) bonded in the main panel.  This will cause the inverter's GFCI outlet to trip - GFCI's typically test for a ground-neutral short (as well as, of course, an imbalance in the hot and neutral currents).

Question: would it be inadvisable to simply connect the GFCI's hot and neutral to the main panel (via an interlocked breaker) and leave the ground disconnected ?   Seems the house would still have a working ground network, and hazards from the inverter are protected by GFCI; the only real hazard would be if the inverter's case became energized.

P.S. Yes, I realize there are other, more complicated, approaches.  A critical-loads sub-panel, which would have to be connected to the main via a breaker that also disconnects neutral.  Or separating the ground and neutral connections onto separate busbars in the main panel, with a ready means of temporarily de-bonding them.

Comment: Because the inverter is also creating a neutral-ground bond because it thinks it is the main panel.  Can't have two N-G bonds in a system regardless of whether it's a GFCI or not. Just the GFCI keeps you honest lol...

Comment: Gotcha.   But do you think the quick&dirty thing that I'm proposing is reasonably safe on a short-term temporary basis ?

Comment: Having just bought the inverter, I could attempt to exchange it for one without a GFCI and non-existent or removable N-G bond (if such even exists at this wattage).  But it seems like the protection afforded by the GFCI offsets any theoretical danger from an unconnected ground.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with GFCI, what doesn't work is the N-G bond at the inverter.

Comment: Even if there were no N-G bond in the inverter, I believe the GFCI would trip when connected to the main panel and its N-G bond.

Comment: Just curious, how did you back feed from the ev outlet did you make a suicide cord? Males on both ends?
They do make inlet connectors that combined with a proper interlock keep you safe. I lifted the neutral bond on my generator I know some have no way to do this.

Comment: Yes, double-male suicide cord.   If I can get this to work, I will certainly install a generator-inlet connector and attach to an interlocked (with main breaker) breaker in the main panel (or in a critical-loads sub-panel).

Comment: Yeah, no way to remove N-G bond on this inverter (or in my panel, since all the grounds and neutrals are attached to the same busbars.

Comment: FWIW, I tried this, not connecting the ground (so my double-male "suicide" cord had only neutral and hot conductors), and nothing bad happened.

Comment: Having been through a similar installation for a much larger generator my advice would be that for 1000W no-engine source powering just a fridge and internet you should use extension cords.  For so many reasons.  It's not worth addressing all the issues that you need to address for such a small system.   And when you need it, running two extension cords will be faster and easier than reconfiguring your load center for the inverter.  Turn off all the breakers, switch over the interlock, hook up the car, turn on the two or three breakers you want.  Then when power comes back on undo it all.

Comment: Our range has electric oven and gas cooktop.   The gas has an interlock and won't work without power.   So even though the oven won't work (zero volts between the two hots), the interlock circuit runs from one of the hots to neutral, so the gas DOES work.

Comment: Instead of posting your answer in a comment, please follow the rules here an post it in an answer. That way it can help others, maybe get an up vote or two, and you can select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing a generator inlet, connected to a breaker interlocked with the main breaker (legal by my AHJ). And not connecting ground in the cord (from 1000watt/120vac inverter to generator inlet). So the cord connects inverter neutral to panel neutral. And inverter hot to BOTH panel hots; decided this was safe, since I have no multi-wire branch circuits (MWBC) in which a neutral could be overloaded with return current from both hots. It does mean 240vac outlets see zero volts, but that's ok since the inverter doesn't have enough power for those appliances anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ground terminal on the inverter connect to anything else.. the inverter (and car) chassis, for example? If it does, and if the ground wire from the inverter to the main panel is not connected, then there could be a potential that develops between the body of the car and other nearby metallic structures (overhead garage door track, stair handrails, ???) as a result of the current flowing in the neutral.

Working with round numbers it seems like you could get 10 A (current out of 1000W inverter) * 1.5 milliohm (resistance per foot of 12 AWG) * 100 feet (path length of neutral from car to main panel) = 1.5 volts developed between car body and anything connected to the house grounding system. If that's applied to a 1000 ohm human body it'll experience a 1.5 mA current, which IIRC is pretty close to the level of sensation for most people and is about 25% of GFCI trip threshold.

I don't know whether a GFCI actually *tests* for a neutral-ground short, but it certainly does *detect* the condition the moment any current flows because half the current returns on the ground conductor, which dodges around the GFCI's current transformer. So you're right: if you *do* connect the ground, the inverter's GFCI will trip.

For any generator, in the Installation and Operating Instructions for the Generac 6294 transfer switch kit Generac recommends disabling the ground-neutral bond in a generator (or, in this case, inverter) used to power a main panel. If that cannot be done - impractical, voids the generator warranty, etc - then use a switched neutral kit accessory in the transfer switch. (see a more verbose version of the same I wrote [there](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/174734/45928).)

The "switched neutral kit" is nothing more than an insulated bus bar and a SPDT relay. The neutrals for the circuits that are to be powered from the GFCI-equipped generator/inverter are moved to this insulated bus bar. The relay common also goes to this bus bar. The relay normally closed terminal goes to the panel's regular neutral bar, ie the one bonded with ground. The normally open terminal goes to the neutral of the generator/inverter. The relay is powered from the generator/inverter.

Taken to an extreme in which all neutrals are moved to the insulated bus bar the relay is effectively a switchable ground-neutral bond. This is basically a validation of what was proposed in your final sentence: "separating the ground and neutral connections onto separate busbars in the main panel, with a ready means of temporarily de-bonding them."

Comment: No, the inverter's ground would be left floating; and I think you're right about what could happen if not.   If I connected it to anything, it'd be an add'l dedicated ground bar (very little trouble if you have a big 3/4" hammer drill).

Comment: I understand about switching the neutral.